# Default selected value for Html Helper Dropdownlist

Tags: html, asp.net, html-helper

I want to create a dropdown list using ASP.NET HTML Helpers and I'm looking for a way to set the default selected value of the list with a single argument (Like the index of the element selected by default for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not directly in the helper but if you use a collection of `SelectListItem` objects, then it is possible with this:

```
List<SelectListItem> items=new List<SelectListItem>();

items.Add(new SelectListItem{Text="Default", Value="-1", Selected=true});
```

More details can be found on this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc).